# what is the benefit if i use body properly position:absolute and display:flex

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

What is the benefit if I use body property position: absolute; and display: flex;

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Position: absolute;**

When you do this: you can set the html's overflow-y to hidden and create a custom (smoother) scrolling for your webpage.

### **Display: flex;**

Personally **I** would not set the display of your body to flex for normal webpages, but just leave it as it is (display: block;).

**But** when you have a body with direct childs, for example: body > div, and these divs needs to devide across the width or height of the window equally, than display: flex; is very useful!

---

So your body styling would be very useful for one-page websites, launch sites and sites with a lot of dynamic (and js). These are basically the benefits I could think of, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

I just do some modification, remove the height and width from body tag.
--------------------
body {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #C0E4FF;
  margin: 0;
_____________________
Working example: http://codepen.io/JEETPAL/pen/wzwXqQ?editors=1100

Comment: That's great! Keep coding :)